# Cloth Sim-Same value but different results, why?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I am an amateur to Cloth Sim. These 2 results under the same values. Why are they different?
Which setting controls the size and quantities of the wrinkles? Somehow, the more I try the more confusing.

Thanks for your time. :D

[image]
There is the mash and one testing above. How could I achieve big folds and higher quantity?

[image: Cloth sim]

Comment: Cloth sim is very dependent on underlying geometry. It would be helpful to update you question with more information - especially showing the geometry of your garments that appear to be behaving differently. This will help soneone replicate the problem to try and explain the difference.

Comment: Hi Rich, I just updated my original post. There is the mesh and setup. Thanks!

Comment: What is the scale of your model? For realistic simulations you really need to fit to real-world scales - so it should be, say, 1m top to bottom. Don't forget to 'Apply Scale' on your mesh (otherwise it will still behave at its old size). I'm not familiar with the 2.8x cloth settings (I'm more used to 2.79) but 5kg vertex mass would seem way too high. If my assumptions are correct that is the effective weight of each vertex in the mesh. So if the whole garment would normally weigh 500g, if there are 500 vertices each should be 1g, not 5kg! I'd suggest get the scale and mass correct and re-try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the scale of your model. For realistic simulations you really need to fit to real-world scales - so it should be, say, 1m top to bottom. Don't forget to 'Apply Scale' on your mesh (otherwise it will still behave at its old size). I'm not familiar with the 2.8x cloth settings (I'm more used to 2.79) but 5kg vertex mass would seem way too high. If my assumptions are correct that is the effective weight of each vertex in the mesh. So if the whole garment would normally weigh 500g, if there are 500 vertices each should be 1g, not 5kg! Set the scale and mass correct for ‘real world’ physics and re-run the simulation.

Comment: Thank you Rich, it is the scale and the geometry. I made mistake I did not make even square faces, so there are heavy area and light area.